# Angular complex project structure

Tags: angular, bundling-and-minification

I am new with Angular. I have some questions:

> 1) Is it possible to rendering components dynamically
>   (something like creating a list of components in a "components"
>   folder) ? My application includes a dashboard page that includes some
>   charts, I have to load these charts dynamically because in future I'd
>   like to create new charts and push them into "charts" folder without
>   editing the application code.
>
> 2) Is there a way to build an application that preserves a
>   folder with all libraries? I always used `ng build --prod` but the
>   result is minified.

thank you

Comment: First question is not clear.. Do you need this? https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/dynamically-loading-components-with-angular-cli-92a3c69bcd28

Answer (score 0):

To disable minification, use

```
ng build --prod --optimization=false
```

This disables optimization of the build output.
All other commands given in below link,

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Do you mean this for first?

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/dynamically-loading-components-with-angular-cli-92a3c69bcd28